# Codeigniter : flashdata between redirect and loading view

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, message

In controller signup

```
    function signup() { 
     if('user already exists') {
     $this->session->flashdata('flsh_msg', 'You have already signed up using goole. you will be redirected to home page.');
    redirect('signup/signup/show_message'); 
     }
 }
```

Show message in same controller, just to show view

```
 function show_message()
  {
      $this->load->view('header/header');
      $this->load->view('signup/signup_message');
      $this->load->view('footer/footer');
  }
```

In View file :

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flsh_msg'); ?>
</div>
```

I am not able to show "You have already signed up using goole. you will be redirected to home page." message on view, I have tested keep_flashdata and set_flashdata.

Is there any other method to do this? How can pass flash message between redirecting and then calling a view

Comment: // if('user already exists') { // where it is come from ? is it variable ?

Comment: No, It is just a condition , in this i have checked "isset" , if return count is greater than 0 etc.

Comment: Instead of writing condition code, i have just mentioned it using text 'user already exists'

Comment: is it working? please check my below answer ?

Comment: I am getting blank value for flsh_msg.  $this->session->set_flashdata('flsh_msg', '############');
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
array (
    [session_id] => 1f85e93b142e5bf0b96d802e9c0168c4
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
    [last_activity] => 1424770709
    [user_data] => 
    [flash:new:flsh_msg] => 
)

Answer (score 4):

> Change in Controller :

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('flsh_msg', 'You have already signed up using goole. you will be redirected to home page.');
```

> View is just as it is :

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flsh_msg'); ?>
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
function signup() { 
    if('user already exists') {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('flsh_msg', 'You have already signed up using goole. you will be redirected to home page.');
          redirect('signup/signup/show_message'); 
    }
}
```

The setting function of flashdata is set_flashdata, not only flashdata.. only flashdata("flsh_msg") will get that string, but set_flashdata set it ;)

Comment: problem was flashdata. Changed to  set_flashdata.. Thanks !!

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND No problem, If you are satisfied with my answer, please click that arrow up and tag my answer as correct, thank you :)

Comment: Daniel Rossko Rosa ...Vote up required 15 reputations. I have only 10

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('flsh_msg', 'You have already signed up using goole. you will be redirected to home page.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Controller

$this->session->set_flashdata('flsh_msg', 'You have already signed up using goole. you will be redirected to home page.');
redirect('signup/signup/show_message'); 

//View

<?= $this->session->flashdata('flsh_msg'); ?>
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps